# How to Set CellEditEnding event for datagrid that is a part of ListView DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, listview, datagrid

I have a problem with setting datagrid event.
I want to register the datagrid inside the ListView with the following event :
**CellEditEnding="dataGridInstallationProperties_CellEditEnding"**
However, since i set the DataContext of this datagrid on the fly, the application throws **NulleferenceException**

Is there a way to get this collection of datagrids inside the list view and set this event programatically in C# for each one of them?

Below is my xaml :

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewInstallProperties"
        Height="Auto"
        Width="Auto"
        ItemsSource="{Binding InstallPackage.Features.FeaturesList}"
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}"
        Background="{x:Null}">
<ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderInstallPropsItemTemplate">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Expander x:Name="expanderInstallationProperties" Header="{Binding DisplayName}"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="0,0,0,-0.001"
                  d:LayoutOverrides="Height, GridBox" Width="600">
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridInstallationProperties"  
                     CellEditEnding="dataGridInstallationProperties_CellEditEnding"
                CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Properties}"
                Margin="0" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.6,-1.231" Background="White"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" RowBackground="{x:Null}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}"
                                        Header="Property"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Header="Value" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Restore"
                                        CellTemplate="{StaticResource RestoreDefaultPropertyButtonTemplate}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Expander>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Extend The Feature To Get Its Related Properties" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ExpanderInstallPropsItemTemplate}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Thanks !

Comment: is binding of the DataGrid working?

Comment: @ethicallogics Hi,Thanks! I set the ItemsSource programatically also for the ListView... Is it connected to my problem?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the exact problem. Is it the CellEditing event of the datagrid not firing or is it that the binding is not working?